How to create services mapped to separate Public IPs without Azure Kubernetes Service adding a Load Balancer rule for each service?
I have a AKS cluster with many applications, each application needs to be exposed to a unique public IP.
I use an nginx ingress controller of type loadBalancer for each application and I'm able to get unique public ip for each application.
This causes the AKS to add LB rules to the load balancer kubernetes which it creates by default for the cluster. Because I have so many applications, it ends up costing a lot as the pricing is based on number of LB rules.
Also I cant use Basic type LoadBalancer SKU when setting up the cluster because I need to use multiple node pools
Earlier I used a single nginx ingress controller which had ingress with all the rules based on hostname and it exposed all the hostnames to a single public IP address.
This caused no cost issues as adding rules in ingress didn't create new LB rules in load balancer.
But now I need separate public IPs for each application.
